# Правильно ли в этом предложении расставлены знаки?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, двоеточие, бсп

*Что-то подсказывало, животное не было куплено, скорее выслежено и выловлено в лесу*.

Объясните, пожалуйста, если есть какая-либо ошибка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Мое решение:**

*Что-то **подскАзывало:** // животное **нЕ было куплено,**/ а скорее **выслежено и выловлено в лесУ**.*

**Пояснение**

1. Это ***БСП***, отношения **ИЗЪЯСНИТЕЛЬНЫЕ.**

Сравнить:  *Что-то подсказывало **(какую мысль?)**, ЧТО животное не было куплено, а скорее выслежено и выловлено в лесу.*  **Содержание мысли** дано во второй части предложения.

2. Интонационное предупреждение (увеличенная **пауза**), поэтому ставится **двоеточие**, а не тире или запятая.
   **Запятая** возможна в нераспространенном предложении, когда первая часть приближена к **вводному** предложению.

**[Розенталь, пункт 3](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=150#pp150)**

```
 Примечание. При отсутствии оттенка предупреждения в 
 начале бессоюзного сложного предложения данного 
 типа после первой части вместо двоеточия ставится 
 запятая: *Слышу, земля задрожала* (Н.).
```

Также **интонационная структура** заданного предложения  исключает постановку **запятой** вместо двоеточия.

3. Желательно использовать союз **А**, чтобы обозначить противопоставление (***НЕ...А***) во второй части предложения.

Answer (score 3):

Добавлю свой вариант:

*Что-то подсказывало, животное не было куплено — скорее выслежено и выловлено в лесу*.

Первое предложение можно считать вводным (запятая после него показывает, что здесь не нужна подчёркнутая пауза), а "кульминация" всего предложения — тире.

Answer (score 0):

***Что-то подсказывало: животное не было куплено, скорее выслежено и выловлено в лесу.***

Answer (score 0):

Лучше так — чтобы отделить сказуемые ***выслежено*** и ***выловлено*** от ***не было***:

***Что-то подсказывало: животное не было куплено — скорее (было) выслежено и выловлено в лесу.***

Ну а если есть возможность внесения в текст правок, то лучше, по-моему, переставить частицу ***НЕ*** и написать примерно так:

***Что-то подсказывало: животное было не куплено, а скорее выслежено и выловлено в лесу.***

Answer (score 0):

**Второй ответ**

Почему в предложении **заданной структуры** нежелательно ставить запятую вместо двоеточия, как это было предложено **в одном из четырех ответов?**

1. Синтаксическую синонимию никто не отменял, и в принципе **возможно** такое решение (с постановкой тире), но семантика будет **немного другая**.

Допустим, у нас есть **вводное предложение** в  первой части. Сравним два варианта с этой семантикой, но с **разной структурой**:

(1) ***Вероятно,** / животное не было куплено — // скорее выслежено и выловлено в лесу.*

Вполне допустимо. **Вводное слово** однозначно относится к первой части предложения и читается с минимальной паузой.

(2) ***Что-то подскАзывало**, // животное не было куплено — // скорее выслежено и выловлено в лесу.*

**Не лучший вариант.**  Прочитать первую часть (до тире) в одну фразу и с минимальной паузой  **сложно**, да никто и не будет этого делать. Паузу  прочитают как обычную при постановке запятой, а дальше еще одна пауза, обозначенная тире.  Предложение делится **на три части**, и вот уже смысл неясен и читать непонятно как.

2. Да и с **ПРАВИЛАМИ** здесь возможен конфликт. ***Подсказывать*** — это переходный глагол,  после которого следует прямое дополнение или изъяснительное сообщение в БСП.  По правилам здесь явно требуется **двоеточие или тире**  (и соответствующая остановка голоса), а все это обозначено **запятой**. Разумеется, **КОРРЕКТОР** обратит на это внимание.

**ВЫВОД**

**Стилистически корректное** предложение должно читаться легко и естественно и так же легко пониматься.  И тогда надо сделать **выбор**: или вводное слово по варианту (1), или двоеточие, а не запятая по варианту (2).